# How to use forEach after computeIfPresent

Tags: java

I have this snippet of code, and I want to use `forEach` after `computeIfpresent` function. Mainly, if the key is found, then we should loop over the values (list), and fetch each entry and add it to another list. Any idea how I can do that?

```
List<Long> myArrayList = new ArrayList();
Map<Long, Set<Long>> myMap = new HashMap();

Set<Long> mySet = MyMap().get(id);
if (mySet != null)
{
    for (Long ex : mySet)
    {
          myArrayList.add(ex);
    }
}

-->??
myMap.computeIfPresent(id, (key, value) -> value.forEach(ex -> myArrayList.add(ex)));
```

Comment: Do you know ther is a method [`List.addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) that does what your loop/forEach does?

Comment: The purpose of `computeIfPresent` is to compute a new value for the entry in the map. The function passed to it as parameter should not have any side effects, and must return the new value.

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: Thank you all. I understand now how it should work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you are looking for `Map.getOrDefault` instead of `Map.computeIfPresent` chained with a `foreach`. Using `Map.getOrDefault` the task could be rewritten to:

```
List<Long> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Long, Set<Long>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
long id = ...;

myArrayList.addAll(myMap.getOrDefault(id, Collections.emptySet()));
```

Comment: Thank you @Eritrean, that's exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 5):

`computeIfPresent` is for changing the value inside the `HashMap` under the given key (`id` in your case). It means that such operation is not allowed because by running `forEach` on the key:value pair you are not providing any new mapping value for a map

What you could do would be

```
myMap.computeIfPresent("a", (k, v) -> {
    ((Set<Long>)v).forEach(e -> myArrayList.add(e));
    return v;
});
```

but it looks bad and is violating the purpose of `computeIfPresent` method

You should just use rather traditional approach

```
if (myMap.containsKey(id)) {
    myArrayList.addAll(myMap.get(id));
}
```

or use an `Optional`

```
Optional.ofNullable(map.get(id)).ifPresent(set -> 
    myArrayList.addAll((Set<Long>)set)
);
```

...but is this more readable? :)